# Configuring mailgun dns txt records

Tags: mailgun, laravel-mail

I am trying to verify my godaddy domain in mailgun. But My second TXT record cannot be verified. I have waited for more than two weeks. Anyone know what is wrong with my setup?

1.mailgun dns txt record
[image: mailgun dns txt record:]

2.godaddy dns management txt record
[image: godaddy dns management txt record 1]

3.godaddy dns management txt record
[image: godaddy dns management txt record 2]

Comment: solve this problem by myself. The godaddy dns management will automatically add my domain name in the host value. I hope i help someone get stuck in here.

Comment: Am having a bit of a problem with verifying the first txt record. Are you using the subdomain 'www' if yes what is host you used for the spf record?

Comment: @dlfjj, Could you please give us more detail about how to resolve it by yourself?